# ABPeoplePickerNavigationController custom instant messenger field not showing

Tags: ios, ios7, abaddressbook, addressbookui

There is an "add instant message" button in the Contacts application.  There are some predefined ones like Skype, MSN, Facebook, etc but you can add a custom one.

However, if you add a custom instant message address, and use the `ABPeoplePickerNavigationController` to retrieve the information, the servicename is always one of the predefined values (like Skype, MSN, Facebook, etc) instead of the custom one you have added.

This feels like a bug to me.  Has anyone else seen this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I can reproduce this in iOS 7, and did not find a similar bug in [Open Radar](http://openradar.appspot.com). Please file a [bug report](http://bugreport.apple.com) with Apple if you have not done so already.